# Is there a way to log who removed reactions using discord.js v12?

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I was wondering how I could log who removed reactions from a message with `Discord.js`. Is there a way to do it?

Comment: Removing reactions aren't logged in audit logs

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [`messageReactionRemove()` event](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Client?scrollTo=e-messageReactionRemove).

```js
client.on('messageReactionRemove', (reaction, user) => {
  console.log(`${user.username} unreacted ${reaction.emoji.name} on this message: ${reaction.message.content}`)
});
```

Comment: This will not return the user object of the person who has removed the reaction but instead the user object from the user whose emoji or reaction emoji was removed